# Not seeing R script folder?

Tags: r, qgis-3

Similar to one of the past questions above I am struggling to see my R script folder. Although despite restarting QGIS3.6.2 and also checking in this pathway:

Options > Processing > Providers, for the R script folder I cannot see it anywhere. I cannot understand why this might be unless it is a firewall I have on my computer that I need to alter.

Is this likely?

How do I do this if this is the case?

Comment: Did you install the plugin: _Processing R Provider_?